# A program that can see the screen and response with clicking the mouse pointer on specific point?

Tags: windows, web-scraping, click, mouse, screen-scraping

Hey there program enthusiasts!
I work from home using a website platform which you can update your status in ("Available","Busy","Logged out" etc.) Once in a while (the time varies) the status turns automatically to "Logged Out". The change comes with a notification on the screen.

What I need is a program that will change the status back to Available whenever it's Logged out. My thinking is that I need 2 components:

1. A program that constantly reads the screen and checks the status
2. A program that moves the pointer and clicks once on the status menu and then on the Available option.

Is this possible on windows 10?

I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks fellows!

Comment: possible create an addon that has javascript to do that? Not to versed in that area though, but that's my initial thought

Comment: if you want to do it programmatically and if you're using Python: [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/mouse_and_keyboard_actions_in_detail/) or [`playwright`](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) both are great options for this task, and both can click on elements. `Playwright` is a modern browser automation library.